# AWS SDK Java V2 SIGNING_REGION_SCOPE ERROR

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am using next AWS dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.34</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is my bean configuration for S3Client

```java
@Bean
S3Client amazonS3Client() {
  return S3Client.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1).build();
}
```

And finally here is my implementation method to upload file:

```java
private void uploadToS3(byte[] fileBytes, String fileKey) {
  PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket("MY_S3_BUCKET_NAME").key(fileKey).build();
  RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.fromBytes(fileBytes);
  s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, requestBody);
}
```

But this code gives me next error log:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION_SCOPE
> at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.EndpointAddressInterceptor.lambda$modifyHttpRequest$1(EndpointAddressInterceptor.java:71)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.internal.handlers.EndpointAddressInterceptor.modifyHttpRequest(EndpointAddressInterceptor.java:71)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain.modifyHttpRequestAndHttpContent(ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:90)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.runModifyHttpRequestAndHttpContentInterceptors(BaseClientHandler.java:164)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.finalizeSdkHttpFullRequest(BaseClientHandler.java:89)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:145)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:114)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:169)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:95)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.putObject(DefaultS3Client.java:8829)
> at xxx.db.repo.message.MessageRepositoryImpl.uploadToS3(MessageRepositoryImpl.java:110)
> at xxx.db.repo.message.MessageRepositoryImpl.doWrite(MessageRepositoryImpl.java:82)
> at xxx.db.repo.message.MessageRepositoryImpl.write(MessageRepositoryImpl.java:56)
> at xxx.service.upload.MessageUploadServiceImpl.uploadMessages(MessageUploadServiceImpl.java:132)
> at xxx.service.upload.MessageUploadServiceImpl.doUploadMessages(MessageUploadServiceImpl.java:113)
> at xxx.service.upload.MessageUploadServiceImpl.upload(MessageUploadServiceImpl.java:72)
> at xxx.domain.UploadDomainManagerImpl.upload(UploadDomainManagerImpl.java:37)
> at xxx.rest.MessageUploadRestController.uploadMessages(MessageUploadRestController.java:31)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at com.xxx.framework.web.filter.OAuth2AuthFilter.authorizeIfNeeded(OAuth2AuthFilter.java:129)
> at com.xxx.framework.web.filter.OAuth2AuthFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthFilter.java:81)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at com.xxx.framework.web.filter.IntegrationLogFilter.doFilterInternal(IntegrationLogFilter.java:68)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at com.xxx.framework.web.filter.TispContextFilter.doFilterInternal(TispContextFilter.java:79)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:97)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

So what is the problem in my configuration so i fix this SIGNING_REGION_SCOPE problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be related to incorrect POM. Hard to say without seeing all of your project files.

However, refer to the following AWS tutorial that will show you how to successfully use the Amazon S3 Java API V2 in a Spring Boot app. In this example, a S3Client object is created by using a  **EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider**:

```java
// Create the S3Client object.
private S3Client getClient() {
    Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(region)
            .build();

    return s3;
}
```

See:

[Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

The use case for this example is you create a dynamic web application that analyzes nature images located in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket by using the Amazon Rekognition service. This app works fine:

[image]